# $abc$ mod $m$ vs division

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider four positive integers $a,b,c,m$ and the modular product $bc = x$ mod $m$.

Theoretically should I not be able to find $x$ by doing $abc / a$ mod $m$? I am not sure how this is done since sometimes there are coprimality issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, co-primality is needed.  This is because the expression $\frac{1}{a}$ has no meaning if $a$ has no multiplicative inverse modulo $m$, which occurs exactly when $a$ and $m$ are not co-prime.  So, the congruence:

$$\frac{abc}{a}\equiv bc\equiv x\operatorname{mod}m$$

is only meaningful if $(a,m)=1$.

An example for clarity.  Notice that since $(2,8)\ne 1$ we have:

$$10\equiv 2\operatorname{mod}8\quad\nRightarrow\quad 5\equiv 1\operatorname{mod}8$$

but since $(5,8)=1$ and the multiplicative inverse of $5$ is itself, we can write:

$$10\equiv 2\operatorname{mod}8\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{10}{5}\equiv \frac{2}{5}\operatorname{mod}8\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2\equiv 2\cdot5\operatorname{mod}8\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2\equiv 10\operatorname{mod}8$$

Comment: When $(a,m)\neq 1$, there are multiple values of $x$ which are solutions to $ax=abc\pmod{m}$. If $x$ is a solution, then so is $x+\frac{m}{(a,m)}$ @user2597879

Comment: @user2597879: Sure.  Look at my example.  Suppose that $abc\operatorname{mod}8$ is $2$ and $a\operatorname{mod}8$ is $2$.  Then $bc\operatorname{mod}8$ could be $1$ or $5$.